# SimpleDateFormat give inconsistent results

Tags: java, timezone, date-format

I am trying to parse a date and I am getting different results when I run the code locally/BST compare to a server in Paris/CEST.

I've reproduced the issue in a the following sample. This is trying to parse the start date for the Australian Grand Prix.

```
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("AET");
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH mm");
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(tz);
    long time = dateFormat.parse("28/03/2010 17 00").getTime();
    System.out.println("Time "+time);
```

It seems like I am setting the timezone correctly on the date format and the current timezone shouldn't be affecting the code. But locally it prints 1269756000000 and in Paris 1269759600000. Any idea?

**Answer:**

It seems like I was testing with an edge case: the Timezone definition is different on my mac compare to the linux server. If I change the timezone to be: "America/Los_Angeles" I am getting a consistent result. The linux box giving me the wrong result is running java 1.6.0-b105 which might be outdated. I'll try an upgrade

Comment: I think it has to do with the default Locale...

Comment: According to Java API docs, 'For compatibility with JDK 1.1.x, some other three-letter time zone IDs (such as "PST", "CTT", "AST") are also supported. However, their use is deprecated'. Did you check if getTimezone is returning null?

Comment: Another possibility would be to not use the Date API of jdk and used instead JodaTime for example. Date and Calendar are quite buggy, so it would not be a surprise that there is a problem with TimeZones also.

Comment: Thanks Matthieu for pointing to JodaTime. I should have used it really...

Answer (score 2):

Interesting. According to the `TimeZone` documentation:

> Three-letter time zone IDs For
>   compatibility with JDK 1.1.x, some
>   other three-letter time zone IDs (such
>   as "PST", "CTT", "AST") are also
>   supported. However, their use is
>   deprecated because the same
>   abbreviation is often used for
>   multiple time zones (for example,
>   "CST" could be U.S. "Central Standard
>   Time" and "China Standard Time"), and
>   the Java platform can then only
>   recognize one of them.

It would be interesting to see the results if you use "Australia/Melbourne" instead of "AET", but just from a quick experiment that I did,  it doesn't seem like it makes a difference.

It's curious that the results are an hour apart, like Daylight Savings Time isn't being taken into account in one of the cases. Stupid question; if you're running on two separate computers, are you sure the times are set correctly on each?

Comment: I tried to use "Australia/Melbourne" but I am getting the same result. Your stupid question is not stupid: I know my server in Paris in something like 10min in advance but that shouldn't make any difference in the code I am running.

Answer (score 1):

On my system here, the result is "1269756000000" (like on your local system). I would try to check the server in Paris, especially the settings that concern the timezone:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.timezone"));
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.country"));
```

Maybe this brings up some differences that helps you to solve this issue.